# Log verbose results of the ASP.NET health check

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, health-monitoring, health-check

Is there a way, when my app first starts up, just before calling app.Run() in Program.cs - to write to ILogger verbose results of all the health checks? That way I have in the log at startup a listing of the health of all my dependencies.